# XCode 4.3.1 and iPhone 3.2 SDK Link Warnings, Directory Not Found

Tags: xcode

After installed XCode 4.3.1, not getting linker warnings as follows:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.2/Symbols/usr/lib'
```

One for armv6 and one for armv7.

In the directory we have...

```
$ pwd
/Applications/xcode.app/Contents/Developer/platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
$ ls
4.2     4.3     5.0     5.1 (9B176) Latest
```

So, I am assuming that the SDK for 3.2 is not present, do we need to reinstall, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the 3.0-3.2.2 Device Debugging Support from Preferences->Downloads->Components